# How is Oja's Rule Applied to Biases?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to implement Oja's Rule for Hebbian Learning (an unsupervised-learning method): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oja%27s_rule

The rule addresses weights. But it makes no mention of how to deal with biases.

1. What is the update rule for biases given Oja's Rule?
2. Would it be amiss to add in the biases before applying the rule?

Here is a simple code example in Python and Pytorch.

```
import torch

input_size = 4
number_neurons = 8
learning_rate = 0.01

weights = torch.rand(input_size, number_neurons)
biases = torch.rand(number_neurons)
inputs = torch.rand(input_size)

outputs = torch.matmul(inputs, weights) + biases
weights_delta = outputs * (inputs - (weights * outputs).T).T

new_weights = weights + weights_delta * learning_rate
new_biases = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

After further inspection/experimentation/analysis, I've found that, in Hebbian learning, biases aren't really necessary in order to map the data to a latent vector space.

Biases are helpful in supervised machine learning using backpropagation in order to create a non-linear relationship. But in Hebbian learning, they are not needed, as the weights are adjusted via relating the inputs and the outputs of the layer with the weights.

If transitioning a Hebbian learning model to a supervised learning model, one can just add a bias vector with the initial values set to some small amount(i.e. 1e-9) before training and backpropagation.

As I found, adding in biases during Hebbian learning while using Oja's Rule resulted in exploding/vanishing weights and outputs. Additionally, the biases prevented any consistently meaningful unique mapping of the data.